# how to get html select to show selected value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a select dropdownlist with 1 item selected at page load in html.

```
<select name = "options">
  <option value = "1">Item1</option>
  <option value = "2" selected>Item2</option>
  <option value = "3">Item3</option>
  <option value = "4">Item4</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to capture new select option when user press shift and select another option such as "Item 3".

I have the following code to find all the selections in the list

```
 var value = "";
 for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < Form.elements[index].length; intLoop++) {

     if(Form.elements[index][intLoop].selected )
             value = value + Form.elements[index][intLoop].value;
 }
```

I can see the "Item 2" and "Item 3" are selected but i want to get capture "Item 3" only. Is it possible?

Comment: you probably want this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp

Comment: Hi alfasin , onselect is Supported by the Following HTML Tags : <body>, <input type="file">, <input type="password">, <input type="text">, <keygen>, <textarea> . i am using <select></select>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's code that will tell you what has been selected and what has been deselected http://jsfiddle.net/8dWzB/

It uses `Array.prototype.indexOf`, and it's not the fastest way to do it. But it should get you going in the right direction.

**HTML**

```
<select id="options" multiple="multiple">
  <option value = "1">Item1</option>
  <option value = "2" selected>Item2</option>
  <option value = "3">Item3</option>
  <option value = "4">Item4</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function getSelectedIndexes(select) {
   var selected = [];
   for (var i = 0; i  < select.options.length; i++) {
       if(select.options[i].selected ) {
            selected.push(i);
       }
   }
   return selected;
}

var select = document.getElementById("options");
var prevSelected = getSelectedIndexes(select);

select.onchange = function(e) {
    var currentlySelected = getSelectedIndexes(this);

    for (var i =0; i < currentlySelected.length; i++) {
        if (prevSelected.indexOf(currentlySelected[i]) == -1) {
            console.log("Added to selection ", this.options[currentlySelected[i]].text);
        }
    }

    for (var i =0; i < prevSelected.length; i++) {
        if (currentlySelected.indexOf(prevSelected[i]) == -1) {
            console.log("Removed from selection  ", this.options[prevSelected[i]].text);
        }
    }        
    prevSelected = currentlySelected;
};
​
```

If you really only want to know which item was last clicked, you can use the following code. I'll use jQuery so I can easily set a handler on all the option objects. Remember this won't work if you change the selection with the keyboard

```
    $('option').click(function(e){
        var parentNode = this.parentNode;
        for (var i=0; i < this.parentNode.options.length; i++) {
            if (parentNode.options[i] == this) {
              console.log('Clicked item with index', i);
              break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Looks good - more elegant than my answer. But doesn't the OP want to know what the last clicked item was? When doing a shift select currently both our answers log ALL the items that were added to the selection.

Comment: If that's what the OP wants... but I don't think that makes sense. Why would you want to know which item was clicked. The only thing that makes sense is what you and I implemented, show the difference between the previous and current selection. For that you can just use the click event on the `option` element, but that won't work if you change the selection with the keyboard, so it's a pretty bad idea.

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted what the OP wanted! Rereading the question I realise there is no requirement that ONLY the last clicked item is recorded.

Comment: +1 because your answer is more elegant than mine and records removed items too.

Comment: Oooh, I get a tingly feeling inside when somebody tells me my code looks elegant. Thanks! I was almost upvoting your answer but then I found that bug and added an answer :p

Comment: I am trying both solutions, Sorry i am slow, I think u 2 solutions could work. I need to know the last click because the options are bug numbers. For some particular bug user select from list, i will have to do something such prompt a message and ask for more information.

Comment: well, do you feel that tingle again ? :D

Comment: @windforceus: Beware that selection can be changed with the keyboard, not just through clicks.

Comment: Hi Juan, i use firebug to debug and i got "select is null" from this line

for (var i = 0; i  < select.options.length; i++) {

Comment: @windforceus Where did you set the `select` variable? You probably didn't give your `select` element an ID.

Comment: Hi Juan, i use ur example, <select id="options" multiple="multiple">

Comment: Did you call `select = document.getElementById('options')`? If you did, did you put it in the load handler? If you just include it in the head, the select element won't be available at that moment

Comment: i did call select = document.getElementById('options'). Where i should put this code? i include in the head.

Comment: The simplest (not the best) way is to wrap all that code with `window.onload=function(){ // code goes here}`  Or just place it all just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the value of the selected options before a change event (e.g. item 1 and 2 are selected) and then again after the event (e.g. item 1, 2 and 3 are selected), and compare the difference.

Here is an example.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FnAuz/4/

I modified your `select` to allow multiple selections since I take it that's the crux of the problem.

HTML:

```
<form id="my-form">
    <select name = "options" id="options" multiple>
      <option value = "val1">Item1</option>
      <option value = "val2">Item2</option>
      <option value = "val3">Item3</option>
      <option value = "val4">Item4</option>
    </select>
</form>​
```

JS:

```
var oldValue = "";
document.getElementById('options').onchange = function() {
    var myForm = document.getElementById ('my-form');
    var value = "";
    for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < myForm.elements[0].length; intLoop++) {
        if(myForm.elements[0][intLoop].selected) {
            value = value + myForm.elements[0][intLoop].value;
        }
    }
    for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < myForm.elements[0].length; intLoop++) {
        var optionVal = myForm.elements[0][intLoop].value;
        if(myForm.elements[0][intLoop].selected && value.indexOf(optionVal) !== -1  && oldValue.indexOf(optionVal) === -1) {
            console.log('Last clicked was ' + myForm.elements[0][intLoop].value)
        }
    }
    oldValue = value;
};
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed that my example works when the user makes command/ctrl selections, but if they make a shift selection then ALL the new values will be counted as the 'last clicked item'. So my code would need some work to account for this scenario. I'm out of time, but hopefully my code is useful in its current state nevertheless!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, yeh, multiple selection is the crux and i am trying your solution. I will let you know , thanks

Comment: This will fail if the select has more than 10 items, because you're using String.indexOf and you would get false positives for 1 if  selected index is 11 http://jsfiddle.net/FnAuz/2/ Try clicking the first item, then ctrl+clicking the last item.

Comment: I am not using JQuery, i prefer to use javascript but if there  is no better option, i will try JQuery.

Comment: Quite right about false positives. I suppose one solution, while still using indexOf would be is the values were not integers (e.g. "val1", "val2" etc. instead of "1", "2" etc).

Comment: As long as no values were substrings of other values, so I think it's usually not a good solution.

Comment: Hi Johnathan, i got error "$ is not defined" form $('.options'), i use <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> to reference Jquery, do i did anything wrong?

Comment: @windforceus His solution is not using jQuery anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var e = document.getElementById("ID_of_Select_Element");
var _selectedValue= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It started looking messy so I'm posting it as an answer:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var value = '0';

document.getElementById('options').onchange = function() {
    value = parseInt(value) + parseInt(this.value);
    alert(value);
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="options" id="options">
    <option value = "1">Item1</option>
      <option value = "2" selected>Item2</option>
      <option value = "4">Item3</option>
      <option value = "8">Item4</option>
    </select>
</body>    
</html>
```

Edition for selecting multiple items:
well, if you want to accumulate items you can assign binary IDs to each product and then you can extract all the selected products from the total. for example, if the total is: 7 you can easily translate it to a binary string "111" which means they selected items 1,2,4. Sounds a bit crazy, I know, just an idea ;)

Comment: Please don't use script in HTML attributes. It's just as easy to do what you did properly separating HTML and JS

Comment: hi alfasin , thanks it works for single select option. I try to make multiple select for the list , so i change it to <select multiple name="options" onChange="myfunc(this.value);"> and press and select "Item 3", the alert shows "Item 2" is selected. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @JuanMendes Let me say it differently, can you be more specific and post your correction ?

Comment: @JuanMendes sorry - I changed it to help windforceus achieve what he wants  and only then I saw your comment - can you please modify my answer again ?

Comment: Edited it again, but I don't think it's what the OP wants, you don't have multiple selections

Comment: oh now I see what you meant. Thanks for the correction!
about multiple selection - I'm not sure I understood what he wants to achieve by doing this, wouldn't it be better to implement it with checkboxes next to each item ?

Comment: Hi alfasin, i am adding this functionality. They already use select for other purpose and yeh, i need multiple selections , sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OP just wants to know which items have just become selected (and I suppose which items have become deselected) See my answer

Comment: Your last answer is the way that Jonathan went. Doing a string search is usually a bad idea, very easy to get false positives, see my comment under Jonathan Nicol's answer

Comment: Not a string search, considering the limitation that you can choose every item only once, the total sum, in a binary representation, provides only one explicit "list of cart items".